# Is it possible to inject a Library into Library?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, dependencies

Is it possible to inject a class library into class library?

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core has its own DI container which you can use as per your requirement.

For Example, below is a simple injectable service.

```
namespace DepedencyInjectionExample.Service
{
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
         string SaysHello();
    }

    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        public string SaysHello()
        {
             return "Hello ";
        }
    }
}
```

For Example, inject service into a DI Container.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
  ...
  services.AddTransient<IHelloWorldService, HelloWorldService>();
}
```

Comment: I know how to inject into startup.cs , I’m referring library to library. Or your ConfigurationService method is used any other Library classs? But NO startup.cs

Comment: You can use simpleinjector library from nuget